# currentgroup() equivalent in sql?

Tags: sql, dax

My dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiNGa.png)

I want to write SQL statement to group by and 1) add Quantity; 2) calculate earliest date based on the group by. In `Dax` I wrote this:

```
Table 2 = GROUPBY(
    'Table',[Region],"Total Quantity",sumx(CURRENTGROUP(),[Quantity]),"First Available",MinX(CURRENTGROUP(),[Availability])
)
```

What is the `SQL` equivalent? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the RDBMS is MS-SQL then the equivalent is

```
select 
  Region, 
  SUM(Quantity) as [Total Quantity], 
  MIN(Availabilty) as [First Available] 
from 
  @t1 
group by 
  Region /*you need to add the grouping columns manually here*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after trial and error, I solved this myself:

```
SELECT product, region, min(availability) as 'First Available', sum (quantity) as N from [table2] group by product, region
```